# which distribution of linux support GMA 3600 now ? Does the latest Ubuntu support?

Tags: linux

I am confused with the GMA3600, i found that there is a method to support it in Ubuntu 12.04. it is that use the old kernel 3.2(do not include gma3600 driver) and install proprietary driver. Now the kernel has include the gma 3600 driver which is in drivers/gpu/drm/gma500, Does that mean all the newest distributions of linux has support gma3600 ? Does that need other user space packages like vesa ?

Comment: According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_GMA_3600: _"The Linux kernel has support since version 3.5."_

Comment: i want to know that whether need some user space package to support Xorg. like i915, there are two part, one is in kernel ./drivers/gpu/drm/i915, the other is in userspace to support Xorg, which is xf86-video-intel

Comment: @approximatenumber

Answer (score 1):

Basic support for GMA3600 (also known as Cedarview) has been available since kernel 3.2, outside of staging ([this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=3abcf41fb1fc6f127ff98d3bae75db7f8f575e47) moved the driver out of staging, [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=b6195aab9ca63a4f6911365f36eb091666fcb15a) corrected the name).

You only need a recent enough kernel; the graphics support is provided via kernel mode-setting, which Xorg supports natively (using its “modesetting” driver). There is no need for a user-space package.

Thus all recent (and many older) distributions should work out-of-the-box, at least if they build GMA3600 support in by default. I think Ubuntu 17.04 should work.

Comment: Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel GMA3600"
    Driver     "modesetting"
EndSection                                                                                     Thanks! Do you mean that adding the content below to */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-gpudriver.conf*

Comment: That shouldn’t even be necessary, it should just work without any configuration.

Comment: Thanks! Should i intall the package named xf86-video-modesetting ?

Comment: No, as mentioned in the answer, there is no need for a user-space package. The modesetting driver is built in to Xorg.

Comment: The Xorg you have mentioned above is the package named xorg-server, like xorg-server-1.17.2. am i right ?

Comment: It’s `xserver-xorg-core`, but you’re thinking too hard about all this — the default installation of any recent Linux distribution should just work on your system, without any tweaking.

Comment: i have installed centos7 , it works well, but i found some errors in file /var/log/Xorg.0.log, that is "EGL_MESA_drm_image required.
(EE) modeset(0): glamor initialization failed". Does that means that gma3600 can use 2D hardward acceleration. Does that normal ? I also found the content "At the moment there is no accelerated driver for Xorg Server, but some support is available using the Xorg modesetting driver provided by package xorg-server. "in https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_GMA_3600

Comment: @ Stephen Kitt       Do you know the following two questions 1) Is 2D hardware acceleration supported for gma3600 in linux? 2)If yes, what package in userspace provide it ? Thanks!

Comment: @zuobiaozhang it’s only supported by a binary blob, but as far as I’m aware no one ships it for current kernel versions (and as a result, current distributions).

Comment: @ Stephen Kitt    But i remember that the binary driver only support 32 bits system, So i think nobody can ship it to current kernel 64 bits version. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

in my Shuttle XS36V where is CPU Intel atom D2700 and GMA3650 working best ***Linux Mint 19.3 Xfce 32 bit***. Videos are smooth and fine playing.
I can installed Linux Mint 20 64bit, but videos what is stored in HDD are chopped and in web browser is OK also in youtube.

```
      Kernel: 5.0.0-32-generic i686 bits: 32 compiler: gcc v: 7.4.0
      Desktop: Xfce 4.14.1 tk: Gtk 3.22.30 wm: xfwm4 dm: LightDM
      Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
```